# Converting bytes32 to bytes4

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am calling a solidity function which returns a byte4 value through web3, which returns the current string:

```
0x15fb397c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I need to convert this string to bytes4. Will truncating it be a "safe" way?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, thats what I do.  Just take the first guys and chop off the rest.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript:

```
const 4ByteCode="0x15fb397c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".slice(0,10)

// 0x15fb397c
```

it will give bytes 4 , its all safe.